# Как сделать автозапуск VNC сервера при включении rasberry pi 3b?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, автозапуск

Пользуюсь rasbian OC.

Пробовал много способов из интернета, но ничего не происходит. По прежнему приходиться запускать VNC вручную.
Один из способов, который не сработал:
Установка VNC:

```
apt-get install tightvncserver
vncserver (придумываем пароль и пробуем подключиться в VNC Viewer)
nano /etc/init.d/vncserver (настраиваем автостарт)
Код https://yadi.sk/i/e0yckvt8PiP9BA
chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver
update-rc.d vncserver defaults
reboot
```

Comment: лучше пользуйтесь RDP, установите xrdp, можно даже на lite os и будет вам счастье, это в разы быстрее работает, на rpi3b проверено

Comment: http://wiki.amperka.ru/rpi:installation:vnc

Comment: Я по этому сайту и устанавливал. Но не вижу чтобы там было что то про автозапуск VNC

Comment: Я бы прибвалил к @PavelGridin совет посмотреть в сторону `x2go`. Оч. норм штука. Статьи на русском есть, роль на ansible тоже.

Comment: в rpi desktop на базе LXDE наверное, тогда `x2go` должен работать, я от него отказался в своё время, так нужен был Gnome и Unity

Comment: @PavelGridin, ну если делается чё-то типа майкрософтовского `remoteapp`, но на базе линукса - туда смысла даже xfce нет. lightdm+icewm - за глаза.